# Quantas instâncias de terminal são chamadas para cada chamada da função exec() em PHP?

Tags: php

Se eu chamar um arquivo, que contém a função `exec()`, em dois terminais diferentes, o segundo vai começar a executar apenas quando o primeiro terminar, ou eles trabalham de maneira independente?

Comment: Dê um pouco mais de contexto à pergunta. Você está tendo algum tipo de problema ao executar comandos com a função `exec()`?

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti estou desenvolvendo um projeto com web service em que tenho um arquivo .php que acessa o banco de dados e, também, faz uma chamada a um arquivo .cpp que calcula as melhores rotas (em um mapa) a partir da manipulação de grafos. Como existirão vários acessos ao servidor, não seria viável usar apenas a função `exec()` caso não exista paralelismo em suas chamadas. Ou seja, se dois usuários fizessem a mesma requisição, ambos receberiam a resposta paralelamente, ou ordenadamente (usuário 2 recebe resposta depois que requisição do usuário 1 é atendida)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para cada chamada a "exec" do PHP você cria uma nova instância do shell em um ambiente Linux, com suas próprias variáveis de ambiente.

No Windows acredito que o comportamento seja semelhante.